# Light stays on without switch connected

Tags: electrical

I have a light in the wash room that stays on when the switch is off and when I turn it on the light gets brighter. I took out the switch and it still stays on . Any suggestions?

Comment: Has it always been like this, or did you change the wiring in some way to cause the problem? Basically, the light is connected to a constant supply of voltage. That's why it stays on.  When you turn on the switch, it's getting more voltage. That's why it gets brighter.

Comment: What kind of light bulb?  LED by any chance?  If so, what happens with a regular lightbulb?

Comment: Is the switch a "smart" switch, timer, or some other fancy doodad?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to answer based on the assumption that this is an plain incandescent and a plain old switch.
Sounds like a couple of things are combining to cause trouble. First, The switch is wired on the neutral rather than the hot side, so there's voltage at the light fixture.  Next, the return line from the light is shorted weakly to ground somewhere, thus completing a circuit and allowing the bulb to light up.  Finally, when you flip the switch, there's a better conduction circuit than the ground short, so the full voltage is seen at the bulb, and it gets brighter.

I would start by carefully removing the bulb and using a multimeter to test both the center contact and the threaded shell of the fixture against a ground point to see if there's voltage there (there should not be).

Comment: I don't even have a switch connected, I took it out thinking it was the switch and the light is still on

Comment: Then clearly the switch is not what controls that fixture.